# Pausing MediaPlayer video and keeping screen visible

Tags: android, video, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I was wondering if there was a way to pause the mediaplayer and keep the screen visible. What I mean by that is keep the current image on the screen as it is paused. What i've done is set up a timer that pauses the mediaplayer for a certain amount of time. As it is paused for that time I want current video to be visable. However, everytime I pause the Mediaplayer the screen goes black untill I call the Mediplayer.start() again. Is there anyway around this.

Thanks

Edit with code

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnPreparedListener, OnErrorListener{

private static final String TAG = null;
MediaPlayer player;
SurfaceView surfaceview;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
int width;
int height;
String path;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    long id = i.getExtras().getLong("id");
    path = i.getExtras().getString("videopath");

    surfaceview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceview.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    playVideo();


}

public void playVideo(){
    try {
        player.reset();


        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        player.setDataSource(path);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        player.prepareAsync();


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
        player.release();
        Log.i(TAG, "Mediaplayer was relased");
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    playVideo();
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    player.setDisplay(holder);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer p) {
    width=player.getVideoWidth();
    height=player.getVideoHeight();

    if (width!=0 && height!=0) {
        surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(width, height);
        player.start();
        player.pause();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                player.start();
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the expected behaviour. A single frozen frame should appear when you put the `MediaPlayer` in a pause state. Perhaps can you show us your code ?

Comment: I've responded to your question and just posted an example.